# DHCP vs WINS

Tags: dhcp, wins

В чем различие?
В чем преимущества?
В чем недостатки?
Зачем 2 протокола для одинаковых нужд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А когда они стали для одинаковых нужд?

DHCP - Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol, производит динамическую настройку хоста. Например установка IP, маски, имени, других параметров сетевых, включая маршруты.

WINS - Windows Internet Name Service, всего лишь ведет список сетевых (NetBIOS) имен. По сути выполняя сопоставление IP-адресов и имен.

Совершенно разные протоколы.